# Android studio- keystore file not found, but does exist in finder

Tags: android-studio, react-native

When making my project in android studio, and when using `react-native run-android`, i get the error: `Keystore file '/Users/corydbaker/.android/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'config'.`

[But as you can see in the picture, the keystore file does exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovpPf.png)

Why would it give me this error?